# jQuery $.post function not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Trying to call this PHP file using the jQuery post method, however it is not doing anything when the button with the class 'reg-btn' is clicked.

Here is my jQuery

```
$('.reg-btn').click(function(){
    $.post('/new-user.php');
});
```

Here is the PHP file, using header to see if its being called.

```
<?php

include_once('includes/init.inc.php');

header('Location: index.php');

?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what do you expect to happen?

Comment: anything showing in the developer console?

Comment: where are the parameters that you want to send? also, `header('Location: index.php');` is not proper response to check whether the AJAX post sent or not

Comment: If you are thinking the `header` is going to redirect you to `index.php` than you are wrong. That is not going to work via an AJAX call.

Comment: Is your jquery being called after the button with the class 'reg-btn' is in the DOM?

Comment: Pass a callback function to `$.post` and see what's in the ajax response. If `init.inc.php` outputs any content, you'll find it there. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/